# "Sync to Outlook" tasks from and to sharepoint for all users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, tasks, outlook

Is there a way to activate **Sync to Outlook** from and to SharePoint for the MySite tasks for all our users?

Every individual user can do it through the ribbon.

But what if we want to activate it for all our users on our on premises installation of SP2013 and Exchange. Is there any hidden option or Powershell parameter to set?

Thanks in advance.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2876938

Answer (score 0):

The feature is getting deprecated, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2998445/en-us, maybe now is not the time to focus on it.